# Cleaning up a PANDAS dataframe of Brazilian football statistics

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am trying to cleanup a dataframe (and the code) in Pandas.

I used to use the `modin` library before but I have since switched from Win 10 to Win 11 and none of `ray` and `dask` libraries work on Windows 11 and I have raised an issue with respective repositories.

In the meanwhile, I am intending to use `multiprocessing` as an alternative to the cause however, I think there can be a better manner in how the code can be written.

I intend to use the

```
def cleanup(x):
    clean df
    return x
df = df.apply(cleanup)
```

way.

```
df.head(20):
    Unnamed: 0                       game score home_odds draw_odds away_odds country                 league             datetime
0            0  Sport Recife - Imperatriz   2:2      1.36      4.31      7.66  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-07 00:00:00
1            1           ABC - America RN   2:1      2.62      3.30      2.48  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 22:00:00
2            2  Frei Paulistano - Nautico   0:2      5.19      3.58      1.62  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 00:00:00
3            3    Botafogo PB - Confianca   1:1      2.06      3.16       3.5  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 22:00:00
4            4          Fortaleza - Ceara   1:1      2.19      2.98      3.38  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 22:00:00
5            5             River-PI - CSA   3:1      3.41      3.07       2.1  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 20:00:00
6            6     Sport Recife - Vitoria   1:1      1.92      3.20      3.93  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-02-02 20:00:00
7            7           CRB - Santa Cruz   1:0      2.22      3.06      3.18  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-29 23:30:00
8            8         Bahia - Imperatriz   2:0      1.31      4.75      8.55  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-29 00:00:00
9            9    Ceara - Frei Paulistano   2:2       1.2      5.43     12.94  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 22:00:00
10          10            Confianca - ABC   1:0      2.09      3.01      3.58  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 00:00:00
11          11   America RN - Botafogo PB   0:0      2.14      3.30      3.11  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 22:00:00
12          12         CSA - Sport Recife   0:1      2.63      3.04      2.62  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 22:00:00
13          13         Santa Cruz - Bahia   0:0      3.72      3.22      1.96  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 20:00:00
14          14        Vitoria - Fortaleza   0:0      3.13      3.02      2.27  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-26 20:00:00
15          15         Nautico - River-PI   1:1      1.44      4.06      6.19  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-23 23:30:00
16          16           Imperatriz - CRB   2:1      2.34      2.94      3.08  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2020-01-21 23:00:00
17          17       Nautico - Campinense   2:0       1.4      4.18      7.26  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2019-05-16 00:30:00
18          18          CRB - Juazeirense   2:1       1.4      4.19      7.32  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2019-05-14 23:00:00
19          19             ABC - AE Altos   2:0      1.44      3.83      7.02  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste 2020  2019-05-08 22:30:00
```

current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv()
df['game'] = df['game'].astype(str).str.replace('(\(\w+\))', '', regex=True)
df['league'] = df['league'].astype(str).str.replace('(\s\d+\S\d+)$', '', regex=True)
df['league'] = df['league'].astype(str).str.replace('é', 'e', regex=True)
df['game'] = df['game'].astype(str).str.replace('(\s\d+\S\d+)$', '', regex=True)
df[['home_team', 'away_team']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True, n=1)
df[['home_score', 'away_score']] = df['score'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df['away_score'] = df['away_score'].astype(str).str.replace('[a-zA-Z\s\D]', '', regex=True)
df['home_score'] = df['home_score'].astype(str).str.replace('[a-zA-Z\s\D]', '', regex=True)
df = df[df.home_score != "."]
df = df[df.home_score != ".."]
df = df[df.home_score != "."]
df = df[df.home_odds != "-"]
df = df[df.draw_odds != "-"]
df = df[df.away_odds != "-"]
m = df[['home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds']].astype(str).agg(lambda x: x.str.count('/'), 1).ne(0).all(1)
n = df[['home_score']].agg(lambda x: x.str.count('-'), 1).ne(0).all(1)
o = df[['away_score']].agg(lambda x: x.str.count('-'), 1).ne(0).all(1)
df = df[~m]
df = df[~n]
df = df[~o]
df = df[df.home_score != '']
df = df[df.away_score != '']
df = df.dropna()
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(
    ['datetime', 'country', 'league', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds', 'home_score',
     'away_score'])]

colt = {
    'country': str,
    'league': str,
    'home_team': str,
    'away_team': str,
    'home_odds': float,
    'draw_odds': float,
    'away_odds': float,
    'home_score': int,
    'away_score': int
}
df = df.astype(colt)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

# Cleaning data where odds are greater than 100 and less than -1 and dropping duplicates
df = df[df['home_odds'] <= 100]
df = df[df['draw_odds'] <= 100]
df = df[df['away_odds'] <= 100]
df = df.drop_duplicates(['datetime', 'home_score', 'away_score', 'country', 'league', 'home_team', 'away_team'],
                        keep='last')
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

df.to_csv()
```

current output:

```
df:
home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds country            league             datetime        home_team        away_team  home_score  away_score
0        1.36       4.31       7.66  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-07 00:00:00     Sport Recife       Imperatriz           2           2
1        2.62       3.30       2.48  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-02 22:00:00              ABC       America RN           2           1
2        5.19       3.58       1.62  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-02 00:00:00  Frei Paulistano          Nautico           0           2
3        2.06       3.16       3.50  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-02 22:00:00      Botafogo PB        Confianca           1           1
4        2.19       2.98       3.38  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-02 22:00:00        Fortaleza            Ceara           1           1
5        3.41       3.07       2.10  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-02 20:00:00         River-PI              CSA           3           1
6        1.92       3.20       3.93  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-02-02 20:00:00     Sport Recife          Vitoria           1           1
7        2.22       3.06       3.18  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-29 23:30:00              CRB       Santa Cruz           1           0
8        1.31       4.75       8.55  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-29 00:00:00            Bahia       Imperatriz           2           0
9        1.20       5.43      12.94  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-26 22:00:00            Ceara  Frei Paulistano           2           2
10       2.09       3.01       3.58  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-26 00:00:00        Confianca              ABC           1           0
11       2.14       3.30       3.11  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-26 22:00:00       America RN      Botafogo PB           0           0
12       2.63       3.04       2.62  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-26 22:00:00              CSA     Sport Recife           0           1
13       3.72       3.22       1.96  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-26 20:00:00       Santa Cruz            Bahia           0           0
14       3.13       3.02       2.27  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-26 20:00:00          Vitoria        Fortaleza           0           0
15       1.44       4.06       6.19  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-23 23:30:00          Nautico         River-PI           1           1
16       2.34       2.94       3.08  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2020-01-21 23:00:00       Imperatriz              CRB           2           1
17       1.40       4.18       7.26  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2019-05-16 00:30:00          Nautico       Campinense           2           0
18       1.40       4.19       7.32  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2019-05-14 23:00:00              CRB      Juazeirense           2           1
19       1.44       3.83       7.02  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  2019-05-08 22:30:00              ABC         AE Altos           2           0
```

Comment: Why do you think that [tag:multiprocessing] would be appropriate?

Comment: Because its a very large dataframe (500 MB) and without [multiprocessing](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/) the code takes about 35 mins to execute while with [Modin](https://pypi.org/project/modin/) it takes about 4 mins. Since I have upgraded to Windows 11, Modin (Ray and Dask) library does not work. I was wondering if multiprocessing can make the job faster. I have a 16 core processor and a 3080 GPU. Multiprocessing can help in this case.

Comment: Another reason not to go to Windows 11 yet. Can you roll back your installation?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yes I can however, if any little case I can help in the case of accelerating the processing of this/pandas workflow/s on Windows 11, it can be great as my son loves the look and feel of Win 11 and I want to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider tightening up this code with the below tips. There may even be room to remove methods that do not seem required with sample of data. Maybe this is legacy code that needs updating.

- **Source**: Check the source of data (i.e., HTML webscraping, JSON mapping, XML parsing) and see if some cleaning can be handled at that endpoint such as splitting the multi-value columns or regex pattern match and replace.
- **Read**: Avoid the many `astype` calls by using the `dtypes` argument of [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). By specifying one type, all columns are parsed into that type but can also specify dict of columns. Note: `string` is different than `str` (synonymous to `object`).

  ```py
  games_df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", dtype="string")

  games_df = pd.read_csv(
      "input.csv", 
      dtype={
          "country": "string", 
          "league": "string", 
          "game": "string", 
          "score": "string", 
          "home_odds": "float64", 
          "draw_odds": "float64", 
          "away_odds": "float64", 
          "date": "datetime64" 
      }
  )

  games_df.dtypes
  ```

  Also, original data shows unnamed column which may indicate a previous `to_csv` export run with default: `index=True`. In `read_csv`, use `index_col` argumemt to assign column as index.
- **Dtypes**: As [recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types) by Pandas authors, use the `String` dtype introduced in v1.0.0 resulting from `astype("string")` and not `object` type resulting from `astype(str)` which the latter can include a mix of string and number types and may cause undesired results down the line.
- **Filters**: Avoid the many returned copies from assignments (`=`) by combining similar filter logic with AND/OR conditions. Consider even [**`DataFrame.query`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

  ```py
  games_df = games_df.query(
      "(home_score != '.') & (home_score != '..') & (home_score != '.') "
      "(home_odds != '-') & (draw_odds != '-') & (away_odds != '-')"
  )

  games_df = games_df[
      (games_df['home_odds'] <= 100) &
      (games_df['draw_odds'] <= 100) &
      (games_df['away_odds'] <= 100)
  ]
  ```
- **Regex**: Avoid `regex` if you can. Current data does not appear to necessitate those many patterns. If much of the issues are handful of string patterns, use explicit string find and replace than generalizing with regex.
- **Aggregating**: Avoid the `agg` calls if you can. Current data does not appear to necessitate those few patterns. Use simpler filters such as [**`Series.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) or [**`Series.str.contains`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

  ```py
  games_df = games_df[
      (games_df["home_odds"].str.contains("/")) &
      (games_df["draw_odds"].str.contains("/")) &
      (games_df["away_odds"].str.contains("/"))
  ]
  ```
- **Strip**: Avoid the `applymap` calls to traverse all rows across all columns. Add [**`Series.str.strip`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) after earlier cleaning.

  ```py
  gamee_df.str.replace('(\(\w+\))', '', regex=True).str.strip()
  ```
- **Write**: Save data especially large content in binary format such as Python pickles for faster read/write and also to retain pandas objects including column types. See [**`DataFrame.to_pickle`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html). Otherwise with text files, you are forced to re-parse data in subsequent steps.